# Where can an app appear in the share menu?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am currently using this piece of code (In the manifest) to appear in the "Photos" app share menu, which is working:

```
<Extensions>
  <Extension ExtensionName="Photos_Extra_Share"
    ConsumerID="{5B04B775-356B-4AA0-AAF8-6491FFEA5632}" 
       TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

What are all of the values that can be placed in `ExtensionName`? Specifically, I would like to place my app in Internet Explorer's share menu, but a list of all places I can place my app would be the ideal answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN Reference : [Integrating with Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202969(v=vs.105).aspx)  Section > **Extensibility**